# Flutter animation with Text going from big to small

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am beginner level with flutter dart. I have check out some videos on how I can implement an animation.

I am trying to animate a `Text` where when the app startup the `text` where its the name of my APP going from Big text to small text.

here is my code, if there is any expert who can guide and correct my code **I would really appreciate**
:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

   AnimationController controller;
   Animation<double> anima;
   double h=700;
 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  controller= AnimationController(vsync: this,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600));
  controller.forward();

}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
    body: AnimatedContainer(
    width: h != null ? 100 : 700,
    curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
    child: Text('here you are', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
   ),
  );
 }

  @override
   void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

I am trying to achieve something like in the pic from pic one to the last one going from big text to small.

from pic 1 to pic 5

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I would really appreciate it, I know its not that difficult for you all there, but for me its really kinda hard to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using Implicit animation widget: `TweenAnimationBuilder`.

And guess what?  You don't need a `StatefulWidget`

Checkout this working sample.

```
class AnimTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: TweenAnimationBuilder(
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        tween: Tween(begin: 700.0, end: 100.0),
        builder: (context, value, child) => Center(
            child: Text('here you are',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: value))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't know that. :D Thank you for that it really helps but now I am more confused since to change the state I read that we need to use `statefulWidget` and you have achieved it without it. can you please tell me what is the logic.

Comment: @AthosTokbi In Implicit animations, you are not the one managing the animation states. `TweenAnimationBuilder` has its own underlying state: `AnimatedWidgetBaseState` where flutter handles the state of the animation.

Comment: Okay, Thank you! Your explanation is much better than the documentation of dev. :)

Answer (score 3):

For this you can use`AnimatedTextStyle`
Var _size = 10;

```
      AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: _size),
      child: Text('this is a test'),
     );
```

Just call setState and change `_size`

Comment: I have tried the code which you have shared but I am only able to see the Amber screen the text is not being animated.